# MySQL Query and display not working?

Tags: php, html, mysql

My MySQL database is setup with the name "chatterr" with the table name, "maillist". I am currently using the php below:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

//query databae
$query = "SELECT * FROM maillist ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed');
$row=0;
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($result);

while($row<$numrows) {
    $id=mysql_result($result,$row,"id");
    $first_name=mysql_result($result, $row, "first_name");
    $last_name=mysql_result($result, $row, "last_name");
?>

<?php echo $id; ?>

<?php
$row++;
}
?>
```

It works on localhost but doesn't work in PHP. What's wrong with the code?

Comment: Why do you have several different `<?php ... ?>` tags? Wrap all of your php code in just one set of `<?php ... ?>` tags. You are splitting up your while loop.

Comment: @Aiias Thats irrelevant to the question, but I am doing that because there is html in between that i didn't upload, since its irrelevant.

Comment: [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions,](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) [they are officially deprecated.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#function.mysql-connect-refsynopsisdiv)

Comment: @Harrison Howard - It's not irrelevant because you are splitting up your while loop and it will not work as you expect it to. Try using the alternate syntax for [php while](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php) loops if you need to split up your code into several php code snippets.

Comment: **What does "doesn't work" mean?** "Doesn't work" is an inadequate description for us to understand the problem.  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Comment: @AndyLester It means i am getting the error "Error, insert query failed"

Comment: @A.Rodas I am using on my localhost for now and i use the newest for online sites. I have no clue what that has to do with anything.

Comment: Your "Error, insert query failed" doesn't help us at all, because it's a message you made up, never mind that the query that failed is a select, not an insert.  You need to print the result of a call to mysql_error instead of making up your own.

Comment: @AndyLester Okay how do i do that?

Comment: `$result=mysql_query($query) or die mysql_error();`  It sounds like you don't know any programming at all, and you're just modifying something that somebody else gave you.  That's pretty dangerous.

Comment: What do you mean it works on localhost and not on php? do you mean it works on localhost and when you upload it online it doesnt work?

Comment: @MuhammadNasir What does that have to do with any question of mine? Sorry, but it just works online, but not on my local host machine. IDK why

Comment: @AndyLester All im getting is:    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/chatterr/new/core/dbconnect.php on line 7

Comment: @HarrisonHoward: My mistake, put the call to `mysql_error()` in parens in the call to die: `die(mysql_error())`.  Beyond that, I'm backing out of this.

Comment: @AndyLester Please help me solve this, all the error that I am getting is "No database selected"

Comment: @AndyLester And i have selected one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select a database with [`mysql_select_db`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php) before querying it

```php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("chatterr");
```

or specify the database name in the query

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM chatterr.students ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4";
```

**UPDATE: Besides that your is connection probably failing.** Change

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
```

to

```
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$db) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

to see if that's the case.

**UPDATE3:** Put it all together. Although that code has a **LOT** room for improvement it works perfectly fine on my machine.

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$db) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db("chatterr", $db);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Could not select db: ' . mysql_error());
}

//query databae
$query = "SELECT * FROM test.students ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed');
$row=0;
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($result);

while($row<$numrows)
{
$id=mysql_result($result,$row,"id");
$first_name=mysql_result($result,$row,"first_name");
$last_name=mysql_result($result,$row,"last_name"); ?>

<?php echo $id; ?>

<?php

$row++;
}
?>
```

> And please, don't use mysql_* functions for new code. They are
>   [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php). Use  [prepared
>   statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo)
>   or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Comment: So would the dbname be "chatterr"?

Comment: If it is your database name then yes.

Comment: Wait the database name or table name?

Comment: Its not my connection, still getting: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/chatterr/new/core/dbconnect.php on line 10.  Line 10 is $result=mysql_query($query) or die mysql_error();

Comment: That's because you forgot parentheses in `die()`. It should be `$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: Still getting the errr "No database selected"

Comment: Then it means that you introduced some other error while editing your code or your database has a different name. See all code in an updated answer. It works fine on my machine.

Comment: Again see updated answer for error handling in `mysql_select_db()` just to make sure that you are actually selecting the correct database

Comment: Glad that it helped :D Best of luck and please seriously consider to switch to `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it this way :

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("chatterr",$con) or die(mysql_error());

//query database
$query = "SELECT * FROM maillist ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $id = $row["id"];
    $first_name = $row["first_name"];
    $last_name = $row["last_name"];
}
?>
```

Comment: I am still getting "Error, insert query failed".

Comment: I just updated my code, you are having error in mysql query. Instead of printing Error Message, it's better to print mysql query error. Try that

Comment: all it says is "No database selected".

Comment: I just updated my code, Now try it, it will 100% work. You didn't select the database in connectivity.

Comment: Still staying no database. WHY? Idk why. I have code to select it.

Comment: Now check with my code, it will show the error in connecting to database.